# How do I change the frame of keyboard word completion view in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, keyboard, frame

Does anyone know how to change the word completion view's frame ?

The view appears when you type in some characters in a text view. but it always appears on the bottom of the character you type.

I found that iPhone message and Skype has put it to the top of the textView, how did they do that? should I define the keyboard myself or just implements some delegate methods?

Answer (score 0):

From what I observe, the autocorrect suggestion is automatically positioned above the line where text is being typed if it is close enough to the on-screen keyboard, such that placing the suggestion below would cause the keyboard to obscure it.

My best guess is that this is determined and handled by the system and that there aren't any APIs to control where the suggestion appears, how to style it, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Firstly , I use UITextField , and the autocorrect suggestion appears on the top of the characters, but the UITextField is only single line. Then I Use UITextView to type in multiple line of content. But I found that the autocorrect suggestion is at the bottom of the characters.

Comment: @yan.sha: Even if the keyboard blocks it?

Comment: I think I may have not clear my question. I mean if I type in Chinese Pinyin, then there will be many chinese word for me to pick, this appears under the Pinyin. I want it to be upon the Pinyin I typed.